# BlueHost avoid main error log

Tags: perl, error-logging, bluehost

My Perl application (in BlueHost hosting) is generating some errors. This error can be shown in the Main Error Log of BlueHost (which is shared):

```
/var/log/domlogs/error_log
```

I don't understand how my errors appears in that file, because in my code I am not referencing it anywhere. How does this process works? Is there any way to avoid my errors appear in that file?

Comment: If this is a cgi application apache is probably configured to send your error logs there.

Comment: As simbabque says, it's likely that the web server is configured to save anything written to STDERR into that log.  This would include the output from `warn` or `die`, or equivalents like `carp` and `croak` from `Carp.pm`.

Comment: So, it is something configured by BlueHost? Is there a way to redirect these outputs to another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect STDERR yourself without needing an external module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

BEGIN {
    open my $fh, '>>', 'myerror.log';
    close STDERR;
    *STDERR = $fh;
}

warn "Hello world";

die "Bye world";
```

The above script closes the default STDERR and opens my own.  It waits to `close` until after the `open` command is called just in case there is some error with the file we're trying to log to.

Log file will report:

```
Hello world at scratch.pl line 11.
Bye world at scratch.pl line 13.
```

Answer (score 0):

This line solved my problem:

```
use Tie::STDERR '>> /home/user/public_html/project/log/error_log.log';
```

I had to install the perl module:

```
Tie:STDERR
```

Information taken from:
http://www.adelton.com/perl/Tie-STDERR/